# Can't make a move in my text based checkers game in java

Tags: java

I have 2 java files for this project. One is the text based console UI and the other is the game logic.

This is the code for the UI:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class represents the user interface for the Checkers game.
 */
public class CheckersTextConsole {
    /**
     * The main method to run the Checkers game.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments (not used).
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckersLogic game = new CheckersLogic();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            printBoard(game.getBoard()); // Print the game board
            System.out.println("Player " + game.getCurrentPlayer() + "'s turn.");
            System.out.print("Enter move (e.g., 3a-4b): ");
            String move = scanner.nextLine();

            move = move.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            if (isValidMoveFormat(move)) {
                int[] coordinates = parseMove(move);
                if (coordinates != null) {
                    int startX = coordinates[0];
                    int startY = coordinates[1];
                    int endX = coordinates[2];
                    int endY = coordinates[3];

                    if (game.isValidMove(startX, startY, endX, endY, game.getCurrentPlayer())) {
                        if (game.makeMove(startX, startY, endX, endY)) {
                            if (game.isGameOver()) {
                                printBoard(game.getBoard());
                                System.out.println("The game is over!");
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid move. Try again.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid move. Try again.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid move format. Try again.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid move format. Try again.");
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses a move string and returns an array of integers representing the coordinates.
     *
     * @param move The move string in the format "3a-4b".
     * @return An array of integers containing the coordinates [startX, startY, endX, endY].
     */
    private static int[] parseMove(String move) {
        if (move.matches("\\d[a-hA-H]-\\d[a-hA-H]")) {
            int startX = Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0)) - 1;
            int startY = Character.toUpperCase(move.charAt(1)) - 'A';
            int endX = Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3)) - 1;
            int endY = Character.toUpperCase(move.charAt(4)) - 'A';

            // Debugging: Print parsed coordinates
            System.out.println("Parsed Coordinates: (" + startX + ", " + startY + ") - (" + endX + ", " + endY + ")");
            
            return new int[] { startX, startY, endX, endY };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the move string has a valid format.
     *
     * @param move The move string to be checked.
     * @return true if the format is valid, false otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean isValidMoveFormat(String move) {
        return move.matches("\\d[a-hA-H]-\\d[a-hA-H]");
    }

    public static void printBoard(char[][] board) {
        System.out.println("  a b c d e f g h");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.print(8 - i + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(8 - i);
        }
        System.out.println("  a b c d e f g h");
    }
}
```

This is the code for the logic:

```
/**
 * This class represents the game logic for a simple Checkers game without kinging.
 */
class CheckersLogic {
    private char[][] board;
    private char currentPlayer;

    /**
     * Initializes the board and sets up the game.
     */
    public CheckersLogic() {
        // Initialize the board and set up the game
        board = new char[][] {
            {'-', 'O', '-', 'O', '-', 'O', '-', 'O'},
            {'O', '-', 'O', '-', 'O', '-', 'O', '-'},
            {'-', 'O', '-', 'O', '-', 'O', '-', 'O'},
            {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
            {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
            {'X', '-', 'X', '-', 'X', '-', 'X', '-'},
            {'-', 'X', '-', 'X', '-', 'X', '-', 'X'},
            {'X', '-', 'X', '-', 'X', '-', 'X', '-'}
        };
        currentPlayer = 'X';
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current player.
     *
     * @return The current player ('X' or 'O').
     */
    public char getCurrentPlayer() {
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current state of the game board.
     *
     * @return The game board as a 2D character array.
     */
    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a move is valid.
     *
     * @param startX The starting X coordinate of the piece.
     * @param startY The starting Y coordinate of the piece.
     * @param endX   The ending X coordinate of the piece.
     * @param endY   The ending Y coordinate of the piece.
     * @param player The player making the move ('X' or 'O').
     * @return true if the move is valid, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isValidMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, char player) {
        // Debugging: Print the coordinates and player
        System.out.println("StartX: " + startX + " StartY: " + startY);
        System.out.println("EndX: " + endX + " EndY: " + endY);
        System.out.println("Player: " + player);

        int xDiff = Math.abs(endX - startX);
        int yDiff = Math.abs(endY - startY);

        // Check for a regular move (one square diagonal)
        if (xDiff == 1 && yDiff == 1) {
            if (board[startY][startX] == player && board[endY][endX] == '-') {
                System.out.println("Regular move.");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Regular move failed due to invalid conditions.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Regular move failed due to xDiff or yDiff.");
        }

        // Check for a capture move (two squares diagonal with an opponent's piece in between)
        if (xDiff == 2 && yDiff == 2) {
            int midX = (startX + endX) / 2;
            int midY = (startY + endY) / 2;

            // Debugging: Print intermediate values
            System.out.println("MidX: " + midX + " MidY: " + midY);
            System.out.println("Board[" + startY + "][" + startX + "]: " + board[startY][startX]);
            System.out.println("Board[" + midY + "][" + midX + "]: " + board[midY][midX]);
            System.out.println("Board[" + endY + "][" + endX + "]: " + board[endY][endX]);

            if (board[startY][startX] == player &&
                board[midY][midX] != player && board[midY][midX] != '-' &&
                board[endY][endX] == '-') {
                System.out.println("Capture is valid.");
                return true; // Capture is valid
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Invalid move.");
        return false; // The move is not a valid regular or capture move
    }

    /**
     * Makes a move on the game board.
     *
     * @param startX The starting X coordinate of the piece.
     * @param startY The starting Y coordinate of the piece.
     * @param endX   The ending X coordinate of the piece.
     * @param endY   The ending Y coordinate of the piece.
     * @return true if the move is made successfully, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean makeMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
        char currentPlayer = board[startY][startX];

        if (isValidMove(startX, startY, endX, endY, currentPlayer)) {
            // Debugging: Print coordinates before accessing the board
            System.out.println("startX: " + startX + " startY: " + startY);
            System.out.println("endX: " + endX + " endY: " + endY);
            
            // Handle capturing an opponent's piece
            if (Math.abs(endX - startX) == 2 && Math.abs(endY - startY) == 2) {
                int midX = (startX + endX) / 2;
                int midY = (startY + endY) / 2;

                // Debugging: Print intermediate values
                System.out.println("midX: " + midX + " midY: " + midY);
                System.out.println("board[" + startY + "][" + startX + "]: " + board[startY][startX]);
                System.out.println("board[" + midY + "][" + midX + "]: " + board[midY][midX]);
                System.out.println("board[" + endY + "][" + endX + "]: " + board[endY][endX]);

                if (board[midY][midX] != currentPlayer) {
                    // Capture the opponent's piece
                    board[endY][endX] = board[startY][startX];
                    board[startY][startX] = '-';
                    board[midY][midX] = '-';
                }
            } else {
                // Handle a regular move
                board[endY][endX] = board[startY][startX];
                board[startY][startX] = '-';
            }

            // Switch the player's turn
            switchPlayer();

            System.out.println("Move is valid.");
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println("Move is not valid.");
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the game is over for both players.
     *
     * @return true if the game is over, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isGameOver() {
        return !hasValidMoves('X') || !hasValidMoves('O');
    }

    public void switchPlayer() {
        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there are any valid moves for a piece of the specified player.
     *
     * @param player The player making the move ('X' or 'O').
     * @return true if there are valid moves, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean hasValidMoves(char player) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                if (board[y][x] == player) {
                    // Iterate through all possible move directions
                    int[][] moveDirections = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}};
                    for (int[] direction : moveDirections) {
                        int destX = x + direction[0];
                        int destY = y + direction[1];
                        
                        if (isValidMove(x, y, destX, destY, player)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have print statements for debugging. According to the output, my move is in the correct format and meets the conditions for a valid move, yet my game still says the move is invalid and won't make the move. I've been trying to figure this out for 8 hours now, can anyone provide some insight into what's happening?

Comment: Putting print statements for debugging is good. But, have you tried running the code in a debugger? You can set a breakpoint on a line of code you are confident worked. Then, you can run the code one-step-at-a-time while monitoring variables.

Comment: Check the `parseMove()` method. Are the returned index values really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The *parseMove* values are incorrect, and you're swapping *x* for *y*.

```java
int startX = Character.toUpperCase(move.charAt(1)) - 'A';
int startY = 8 - Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0));
int endX = Character.toUpperCase(move.charAt(4)) - 'A';
int endY = 8 - Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3));
```

Comment: Ok, I have x and y right and the math seems correct now based on this output:

Enter move (e.g., 3a-4b): 3a-4b
Parsed Coordinates: (2, 0) - (3, 1)
StartX: 2 StartY: 0
EndX: 3 EndY: 1
Player: X
Regular move failed due to invalid conditions.
Invalid move.

But it's still failing to recognize the move as valid even though everything seems in order. What am I missing?